# Why is global json object null inside on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code I have a global variable set to a json string but when I try to access it inside the el.on function its logs as null. If I change child_strings = 'test'; it works fine.

What is going on?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var child_strings = JSON.parse('{"Open":["Open_New","Closed_Closed","Open_Pending Input","Open_Pending","Open_CARD","Open_Open","Closed_Rejected"],"Closed":["Open_DAD","Closed_Duplicate","Open_Assigned"]}');
    if ("1") {
        if (typeof de_entries == 'undefined') {
            var de_entries = new Array;
        }
        var el = $("#state");
        el.on('change', function() {
            console.log(child_strings);
            alert(child_strings);
            updateDynamicEnum("state", "status", child_strings)
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is this the exact code?

Comment: Why not just create the object directly instead of deserialising a string constant? Also, if the `child_strings` is supposed to be global, why pass it to the function? What you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bfke83j5/

Comment: Yes but its lifted from a much larger application.

Comment: Try wrapping the whole code inside an anonymous function or declare the variable explicitly global: `window.child_strings = ` or leave out the `var`: `child_strings = `

Comment: The variable is generated with a php call like so:  echo "var child_strings = JSON.parse('".json_encode($child_strings)."');";

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Either way it is still null when I try to access it inside updateDynamicEnum

Comment: @user794846: So it's only null inside `updateDynamicEnum`? Or it's also null in the `log` and `alert`s?

Comment: I am not a PHP guy, but looks like you evaluation is happening after the on function is executed. are you sure var child_strings is evaluated before on function? Can you try a alert and see if it is evaluated before on?

Comment: You are facing a scope issue which we cannot be aware of regarding your posted code. So set variable explicitely as global, removing `var` statement e.g.

Answer (score 1):

There must be another scope within your application. The code you provide works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/afzza446/

Check whether the declaration of the variable is not in a scope. You can try to declare the variable like that (without `var`):

```
    child_strings = JSON.parse('{"...
```

Or explicitly add it to the global window object:

```
window.child_strings = ...
```

Comment: Tried both and it still results in the same issue.

Comment: then we need to see more code

Comment: What I dont get is if I set it to child_strings = 'bla'; it works fine. Why is it only the json object that wont work even if I child_strings = JSON.stringify(child_strings); and pass that in it still wont accepted it.